# If I updated a file inside a node module how can I make a new build out of it?

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts, vue-material

I'm trying to change a certain file in the library called
vue-material, inside vue-material's component folder there are 
bunch folders, but I'm only trying to change one file (it is from one of the developers of the library) which is the fix for the current bug I am experiencing.

The problem is even if I overwrite the file with the fix , my program will not get
affected by it ,probably because it is using the build file in the dist folder.
So my question is how can I build files in the node module?

Comment: You need to fork it.

Comment: from the github ?

Comment: Modifing a library is not a good idea. Updating gets harder and npm install will not include your changes. Is there some other way?

Comment: the devs of the library made the changes for me , I am just trying to use the fix.

Comment: @Johji if the devs made changes, install the new version with those changee.

Comment: you mean delete the npm module folder then 'npm install' again?

Comment: @Johji Simply `npm update` or `npm update PACKAGE`